# Electric field at point without change in magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider that a magnetic field, increasing with time exists within the circle shown in the figure:

[image: Diagram]

Consider 2 points A and B at equal distance from the centre.
According to Faraday's law, $ ε = -\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$ within OABO. My professor says that due to an increasing magnetic field, circularly looping electric field lines will be observed around the circle- which are perpendicular to OA and OB and thus no EMF is generated between OA and OB. Then $ε_{AB} = -\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}$.

My confusion is, since there is no magnetic field between AB, changing or otherwise, how come any electric field or electromotive force is generated there?

Comment: Why would there be no magnetic field between AB? Unless your circle is a (purely hypothetical) material that blocks the field, there will exist a magnetic field between AB

Comment: I had the same doubt. But it is defined such in the problem. Am I to take it that such a situation cannot exist?

Comment: I would say so. A magnetic field completely in free space should extend to infinity, albeit decreasing at a rate ~ 1/r^3 where r is your separation distance. I think you may have missed important details out in your description of the problem though. For example, is the magnetic field being generated by a current on the loop around O?

Comment: @Christian it's not uncommon to have unphysical fields like this in introductory physics classes (assumption that this is introductory).

Comment: @Christian the problem is just this much. I guess it is just to give high schoolers a feel of Faraday's law; however am I correct in thinking that without there being a time-varying magnetic field at some point there cannot be an electric field there? If there is no electric field in my frame

Comment: @Sid yes that is correct